# Find all four digit numbers such that sum of digits is $13$ and digits aren't $0$

Tags: combinatorics

This is how I tried to solve it:

If $x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}x_{4}$ is our number then $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}=13$.
Because the number cannot contains $0$ then $x_{i}\geq 1 $ for $1\leq i\leq 4$.

So, the answer is the number of non-negative solutions to the equation :

$x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}=9$.

And by using stars and bars the number of solutions is
${9+4-1 \choose 4-1}={12 \choose 3}=220$.

The teaching assistant published the "correct" answer. Which is **640**. But it can be wrong.

I don't understand where I am wrong.

The correcte answer is 216 as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: $640$ seems very high.  There are only $9^4=6561$ four digit numbers without a $0$...we're to believe that $10\%$ of them have digit sum $13$?

Comment: A small point is that, in your second equation, the largest digit available is 8. So the composition $9+0+0+0$ and its four permutations are not valid solutions, further reducing the count to 216.

Comment: I thought the same thing but that's the answer our teaching assistant published. But I'm open to other answers, maybe it was a mistake on his part and maybe not. Unfortunately he didn't published his detailed solution

Comment: It's not particularly difficult to automate the computation. Maybe worth it to probe the point.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yeah, I didn't take that into account. But still according to the "official" answer it's still incorrect

Comment: @lulu True. But I want to understand the general approach to this kind of problems

Comment: Of course, but it's always good to be able to check and this problem is right at the edge of what can be computed easily.  Too hard for pencil and paper, but a quick program.  If you get $216$ then your method is confirmed (Spoiler Alert:  $216$ is correct).

Comment: Should note:  These computations are very error prone (as you see from the fact that you missed the cap).  It is *always* good to check things in as much as you can.  And here you have the extra motivation in that you were given an official solution which defied your computation (and which defies common sense, but that's another story).

Comment: You are right. It can't hurt to check and thanks a lot! It really seems the correct answer is 216 as you two said

Comment: For what it's worth, here is the [Mathematica output](https://i.imgur.com/7HbC2Vk.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question was simply finding the number of solutions to $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}=13$ in positive integers then the answer, again using *stars and bars*, would have been ${13-1 \choose 4-1}= {12 \choose 3}=220$, as with your calculations.

But you are restricted to decimal digits apart from $0$.  So the solution $10+1+1+1=13$ needs to be excluded, as do solutions with the same terms in a different order.  No other solution needs to be excluded in this case.

So the result is $220-4=216$.